# How do I set up Java Opengl on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl

so I'm just getting into Java Opengl, and I use eclipse as my IDE. I checked the Java Opengl website, but it doesn't really help you to install it. Can anyone give me some steps on how to install Java Opengl so that it can be used in eclipse?

I'm using windows 64 btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to install JOGL or LWJGL to use OpenGL in Java

- Instructions for JOGL: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial
- LWJGL: https://www.lwjgl.org/guide (there should be a versioned installation link pointing to github)

p.s.: Some JOGL vs. LWJGL discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644872/revisiting-the-issue-of-lwjgl-vs-jogl-for-game-programming

Comment: All the links above are dead, please consider updating them.